# Software to combine two videos of the same scene?

Tags: software

I think this software idea seems simple enough to have been created, but it might be so specific that no one has done it. I'm just wondering if it already exists.

I'm looking for some program which takes two videos which have identical backgrounds (or nearly identical, there are likely slight intensity differences in pixels) and allows you to combine the dynamical elements of each into a single video. For example, If I have a video of a room where I'm standing on the left side of the room, then another video from the same view where I'm standing on the right, and then the program would combine the two so I'm standing on both left and right. I guess things like shadows and whatnot would cause some problems here, but the general idea shouldn't be too ridiculous. Does something like this exist?

Thank you much!

Comment: You can use a compositing software (or even a video editor with basic masking capability) to create mask for one video which you then put on top of the other. Normally these things are done with masking/mattes (simple, rotoscoped) and often objects recorded against a green screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I might expand a bit on the previous answers here. They're both correct, just not very informative.

What you are after is a technique often called the cloning or twin effect. As you have already stated, it consists of filming two different clips against the same background and then layering them over eachother.

This can be achieved in almost any conventional video editing program (even Windows Movie Maker and iMovie) - so which one you choose depends only on your own preferences and other needs.

However, [here is a video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX5eVFye4I) of how to do it in Premiere Elements. This should help show you the basic technique. If you need more specific help with whatever other piece of software you want to use, simply googling it will give you some great links. ;) Also, if anyone wants to specific video tutorials on how to do this in other video editing programs - feel free to edit (or comment on) this post.

I hope that was of help to you - and if you need more help I'll gladly assist.

Answer (score 1):

Sony Vegas Pro can do it but it is a bit pricey. In general, you need any video editor that supports masking and compositing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out After Effects, this is a pretty easy thing to do within using masks...You can download a 30-day free trial at adobe.com